# How to write a SQL statement?

Tags: sql

I would like to know the SQL statement to cover the following problem.I have some problem in here.

```
SupplierID  ContractStart   ContractEnd         

20          1/1/2010        1/3/2010
24          12/12/2008      12/1/2009
31          13/1/2008       13/2/2008
20          13/1/2008       13/2/2008
24          11/11/2007      11/12/2010
31          12/12/2008      1/1/2009
```

Please identify the Supplier ID that overlapping contract in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is `t`, this should do it:

```
select a.supplierid, b.supplierid
from t a, t b
where ((b.contractstart<a.contractend and b.contractend>a.contractend)
    or (a.contractstart<b.contractstart and a.contractend>b.contractstart))
    and a.supplierid<b.supplierid -- strict so you don't get doubles
```

Edit: This is assuming your duplicate ID's are typos.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.sid 
FROM contracts a, contracts b
WHERE a.sid == b.sid
AND a.start < b.start
AND a.end > b.start;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to identify overlap by supplier id this should work:

FYI I used mm/dd/yyyy

```
declare @contract table ( SupplierID int, ContractStart datetime, ContractEnd datetime)

insert into @contract
select 20, '1/1/2010', '3/1/2010'
union all
select 24 , '12/12/2008', '1/12/2009'
union all
select 31, '1/13/2008 ', '2/13/2008'
union all
select 20, '1/13/2008', '2/13/2008'
union all
select 24, '11/11/2007 ', '12/11/2010'
union all
select 31, '12/12/2008 ', '1/1/2009'

SELECT a.supplierid, 
       a.contractstart, 
       a.contractend, 
       b.contractstart, 
       b.contractend 
FROM   @Contract a 
       INNER JOIN @Contract b 
         ON b.supplierid = a.supplierid 
WHERE  ( b.contractstart < a.contractend ) 
       AND ( b.contractend > a.contractstart ) 
       AND ( b.contractstart != a.contractstart --Ignore overlap with self
             AND b.contractend != a.contractend ) 
       AND b.contractstart > a.contractstart -- No Duplicates
```